# How to use AsyncTask with ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter, getview

So, I have a `ListView` which I'm showing on my `TodayFragment`. There are `TodayTaskAdapter`, that customises this list. When the actvity is loading, it takes a lot of time because of the list. And slows down app. The question is:

### How should I use AsyncTask right? And what is the right place to use it:

1. In fragment, when setting adapter;
2. In `getView()` method of adapter to do the operation there in
   backgroud;
3. Or someplace else?

I'm not quite into it yet. Need help.

### **TodayFragment**

```
public class TodayFragment extends AbstractTabFragment
{
    public static final String TODAY_PAGE = "TODAY_PAGE";
    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_today;

    private ListView task_list;

    private TodayTaskAdapter today_task_adapter;

    private Event event;
    private Event event1;
    private Event event3;

    private Event event4;
    private Event event5;

    private Event event6;
    private Event event7;

    private Event event8;
    private Event event9;

    public static TodayFragment newInstance(int page, Context context)
    {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TODAY_PAGE, page);

        TodayFragment fragment = new TodayFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.setContext(context);
        fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tab_today_name));

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

        task_list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_list);

        today_task_adapter = new TodayTaskAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.today_list_item);

        eventCreation();

        today_task_adapter.add(new EventTypeSection("Schedule"));
        today_task_adapter.add(event);
        today_task_adapter.add(event1);
        today_task_adapter.add(event3);

        today_task_adapter.add(new EventTypeSection("ToDo"));
        today_task_adapter.add(event4);
        today_task_adapter.add(event5);

        today_task_adapter.add(new EventTypeSection("Work Task"));
        today_task_adapter.add(event6);
        today_task_adapter.add(event7);

        today_task_adapter.add(new EventTypeSection("Birthday"));
        today_task_adapter.add(event8);
        today_task_adapter.add(event9);

        task_list.setAdapter(today_task_adapter);

        return view;
    }

    private void eventCreation()
    {
        event = new Schedule(1,"Algorythm Theory", ScheduleType.LESSON, "10:20 AM", "11:55 AM", "07.01.2017", EventType.SCHEDULE, "Waiting", 79);
        event1 = new Schedule(2,"Object-oriented programming", ScheduleType.LABORATORY_WORK, "12:00 AM", "01:30 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.SCHEDULE, "Waiting", 63);
        event3 = new Schedule(2,"Aplied Math", ScheduleType.EXAM, "01:50 PM", "03:35 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.SCHEDULE, "Waiting", 17);

        event4 = new ToDo(5,"Clean house", "09:30 AM", "03:35 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.TODO, "Waiting", 91);
        event5 = new ToDo(7,"Buy grocery and other things", "01:30 AM", "02:25 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.TODO, "Waiting", 23);

        event6 = new WorkTask(5,"Refactoring", "09:30 AM", "01:35 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.WORKTASK, "Waiting", 81);
        event7 = new WorkTask(7,"Build database", "04:30 PM", "05:25 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.WORKTASK, "Waiting", 33);

        event8 = new Birthday(8,"Taras's birthday", "09:30 AM", "01:35 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.BIRTHDAY, "Waiting", 71, new Location(1, 2, "Roksolany", "Lviv", "Ukraine"));
        event9 = new Birthday(9,"John's birthday", "04:30 PM", "05:25 PM", "07.01.2017", EventType.BIRTHDAY, "Waiting", 53, new Location(1, 2, "Roksolany", "Lviv", "Ukraine"));
    }
}
```

### **TodayTaskAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.twinkle94.dealwithit.R;
import com.example.twinkle94.dealwithit.events.Event;
import com.example.twinkle94.dealwithit.events.task_types.Schedule;
import com.example.twinkle94.dealwithit.events.type_enums.EventType;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TodayTaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private final String NAME = TodayTaskAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_LIST = 1;

    private List<Item> list_of_tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public TodayTaskAdapter(Context context, int resource)
    {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public void add(Item event)
    {
        list_of_tasks.add(event);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return list_of_tasks.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position)
    {
        return list_of_tasks.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return getItem(position).getType() == EventType.NO_TYPE ?
                RowType.HEADER_ITEM.ordinal()
                :
                RowType.LIST_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return RowType.values().length;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
    {
        EventViewHolder eventViewHolder;

        // Get the data item type for this position
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            eventViewHolder = new EventViewHolder();

            // Inflate XML layout based on the type
            convertView = getInflatedLayoutForType(type, parent);

            switch (type)
            {
                case TYPE_HEADER:
                    initHeader(convertView, eventViewHolder);
                    break;

                case TYPE_LIST:
                    initViews(convertView, eventViewHolder);
                    break;
            }

            convertView.setTag(eventViewHolder);
        }

        else
        {
            eventViewHolder = (EventViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //set all views with values from list
        setViewValues(position, eventViewHolder);

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setViewValues(int position, EventViewHolder eventViewHolder)
    {
        Item event = getItem(position);

        int type_color;
        String task_title;
        String from_time;
        String to_time;
        String importance;
        String interest;

        if (event != null)
        {
            switch (event.getType())
            {
                case SCHEDULE:
                    type_color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeSchedule);
                    task_title = ((Event)(event)).getTitle();
                    String schedule_type = ((Schedule)(event)).getScheduleType().toString();
                    int schedule_type_image = getSchedule_type_image(event);
                    from_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_start();
                    to_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_end();
                    importance = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance()) + "%";
                    interest = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance() + 9) + "%";

                    eventViewValues(eventViewHolder, type_color, task_title, schedule_type_image, schedule_type, from_time, to_time, importance, interest, View.VISIBLE, View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                case TODO:
                    type_color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeToDo);
                    task_title = ((Event)(event)).getTitle();
                    from_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_start();
                    to_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_end();
                    importance = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance()) + "%";
                    interest = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance() + 9) + "%";

                    eventViewValues(eventViewHolder, type_color, task_title, 0, "", from_time, to_time, importance, interest, View.GONE, View.GONE);
                    break;

                case WORKTASK:
                    type_color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeWorkTasks);
                    task_title = ((Event)(event)).getTitle();
                    from_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_start();
                    to_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_end();
                    importance = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance()) + "%";
                    interest = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance() + 9) + "%";

                    eventViewValues(eventViewHolder, type_color, task_title, 0, "", from_time, to_time, importance, interest, View.GONE, View.GONE);
                    break;

                case BIRTHDAY:
                    type_color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeBirthday);
                    task_title = ((Event)(event)).getTitle();
                    from_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_start();
                    to_time = ((Event)(event)).getTime_end();
                    importance = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance()) + "%";
                    interest = Integer.toString(((Event)(event)).getImportance() + 9) + "%";

                    eventViewValues(eventViewHolder, type_color, task_title, 0, "", from_time, to_time, importance, interest, View.GONE, View.GONE);
                    break;

                case NO_TYPE:
                    String type = ((EventTypeSection) getItem(position)).getTitle();

                    eventViewHolder.headerText.setText(type);

                    switch(type)
                    {
                        case "Schedule":
                            eventViewHolder.headerText.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeSchedule));
                            break;

                        case "ToDo":
                            eventViewHolder.headerText.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeToDo));
                            break;

                        case "Work Task":
                            eventViewHolder.headerText.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeWorkTasks));
                            break;

                        case "Birthday":
                            eventViewHolder.headerText.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorTypeBirthday));
                            break;

                    }

                    break;

                //TODO: add default, when task have no type.
            }
        }
    }

    private int getSchedule_type_image(Item event)
    {
        int schedule_type_image = R.drawable.ic_lesson_type;

        switch(((Schedule)(event)).getScheduleType())
        {
            case LESSON:
                schedule_type_image = R.drawable.ic_lesson_type;
                break;

            case EXAM:
                schedule_type_image = R.drawable.ic_exam_schedule_type;
                break;

            case LABORATORY_WORK:
                schedule_type_image = R.drawable.ic_lab_work_schedule_type;
                break;
        }
        return schedule_type_image;
    }

    //TODO: overload method with less parameters for different types of tasks.
    private void eventViewValues(EventViewHolder eventViewHolder, int type_color, String task_title, int scheduleTypeImage, String schedule_type,
                                 String from_time, String to_time, String importance, String interest,
                                 int task_type_visibility, int task_type_image_visibility)
    {
        eventViewHolder.type_color.setBackgroundColor(type_color);

        eventViewHolder.task_title.setText(task_title);
        eventViewHolder.task_type.setText(schedule_type);
        eventViewHolder.task_type_image.setImageResource(scheduleTypeImage);

        eventViewHolder.task_type.setVisibility(task_type_visibility);
        eventViewHolder.task_type_image.setVisibility(task_type_image_visibility);

        eventViewHolder.from_title.setText("From");
        eventViewHolder.from_time.setText(from_time);
        eventViewHolder.from_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_from_time);

        eventViewHolder.to_title.setText("To");
        eventViewHolder.to_time.setText(to_time);
        eventViewHolder.to_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_to_time);

        eventViewHolder.importance.setText(importance);
        eventViewHolder.importance_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_importance_icon);

        eventViewHolder.interest.setText(interest);
        eventViewHolder.interest_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_interest_today_page);
    }

    private View getInflatedLayoutForType(int type, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View inflated_view = null;

        switch(type)
        {
            case TYPE_HEADER:
                inflated_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.today_list_header, parent, false);
                break;

            case TYPE_LIST:
                inflated_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.today_list_item, parent, false);
                break;
        }

        return inflated_view;
    }

    private void initHeader(View row, EventViewHolder eventViewHolder)
    {
        eventViewHolder.headerText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tasks_title);
    }

    private void initViews(View row, EventViewHolder eventViewHolder)
    {
        eventViewHolder.type_color = row.findViewById(R.id.type_color);

        eventViewHolder.task_title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        eventViewHolder.task_type = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.task_type);
        eventViewHolder.task_type_image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.lesson_type);

        eventViewHolder.from_title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.from_title);
        eventViewHolder.from_time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.from_time);
        eventViewHolder.from_image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.from_time_icon);

        eventViewHolder.to_title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.to_title);
        eventViewHolder.to_time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.to_time);
        eventViewHolder.to_image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.to_time_icon);

        eventViewHolder.importance = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.importance_percent);
        eventViewHolder.importance_image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.importance_icon);

        eventViewHolder.interest = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.interest_percent);
        eventViewHolder.interest_image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.interest_icon);
    }

    private static class EventViewHolder
    {
        View type_color;

        TextView task_title;
        TextView task_type;
        ImageView task_type_image;

        TextView from_title;
        TextView from_time;
        ImageView from_image;

        TextView to_title;
        TextView to_time;
        ImageView to_image;

        TextView importance;
        ImageView importance_image;

        TextView interest;
        ImageView interest_image;

        //Header text
        TextView headerText;
    }

    private enum RowType
    {
        HEADER_ITEM, LIST_ITEM
    }
}
```

Comment: `When the actvity is loading, it takes a lot of time because of the list.` - I think you need to question why your list takes a long time to populate rather than assuming it needs to be asynchronous. in regards to async task - you cannot perform any view operations (i.e. `textView.setText("some text");`)  from any other thread than the main ui.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But I saw in documentation this: 
`public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // a potentially  time consuming task
            final Bitmap bitmap =
                    processBitMap("image.png");
            mImageView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}`
It's not asynctask, but still the other thread and it uses UI elements than informs main thread about changes.

Comment: That `mImageView.post()` code in your coment example puts the manipulation of the `ImageView` back on the UI thread. Are you still looking for an answer to your question?

Comment: @Cheticamp,  yes,  I'm still looking.  If you have one,  share please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list may take a long time to load for various reasons: size of the data, slow connection to backend server, high computational demand, etc. Often these time-consuming tasks are just going to take some time and there is nothing we can do about it except to try to minimize the impact on the user.

The goal of doing background processing with `AsyncTask`, `Loader`, etc. is to take a time-consuming task and move it off of the thread that runs the user interface (the UI thread) and overlap processing as much as possible so the app does not appear to "hang." So, start the `AsyncTask` as soon as you can. Depending upon your app, the processing may be completed by the time the user needs to see the resulting data which would be great. If not, then you may have to throw up a `ProgressBar` to let them know that they will need to wait a little. The `onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()` methods of `AsyncTask` will help you communicate with the user (on the UI thread) about the progress your app is making in getting data. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)).

Also take a look at [this example](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-async-listview-jee-and-restful.html). The `AsyncTask` is invoked right after the `ListView` adapter is set. This is a common place to do this. That would be in your fragment. (`getView()` is not the right place.)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

adpt = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList(), this);
ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

lView.setAdapter(adpt);

// Exec async load task
(new AsyncListViewLoader()).execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/JSONServer/rest/ContactWS/get");
}
```

If you have a lot of data to show, then you may want to implement some logic to do endless scrolling where you show a page or two of data before fetching more. Just search for "listView endless scrolling" for additional information on this.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I wanted to ask one more thing. I've made AsyncTask like this [link](https://codepaste.net/frinfw) for list. Is it good? 
And called in fragment: [link](https://codepaste.net/ghkv7p). But is one problem. Sometimes app crashes. because it can't see context.

Comment: Everything looks good. Where are you storing `context` that `onActivityCreated()` can't see it? Can't see it or is it null or does it throw some other exception?

Comment: oh, sorry, from this method it works fine, but from `onCreateView()` [fragment](https://codepaste.net/ba9f8b)  it gives me `NullPointerException`. But, I think it doesn't see the list, but don't know why(

[error](https://codepaste.net/8f6qgs)

Comment: It's not clear from your code for `onCreateView()` where `context` is coming from. Is it a class member variable? It has to be. Make sure that it is set to the `Activity` for the fragment. You are having trouble capturing the right context or any context at all. What is `setContext()`? I would check that out to make sure it is doing what you want. Contexts can be tricky things. There is, fortunately, a lot of guidance on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah, it's class member from `AbstractFragment` [absFrag](https://codepaste.net/8dfp53). 
This is `Context` that I give to fragments [context](https://codepaste.net/7q7q6c).
And this kind of context I give to list. [initList](https://codepaste.net/a4gcgf).

Comment: Make sure that  context is defined and set to your `Activity` in this statement - new TodayTaskListLoader(context).execute(). If it is null, or not set correctly, then this statement (`task_list = (ListView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.tasks_list)`) will give you null that results in the NPE that you are seeing.

Comment: Can't now. Would have to be late tomorrow.

Comment: The context is set on all stages, but, I guess sometimes background task is loaded faster than UI and context is set to null in that case. So exception arrives. Maybe, I should move it to onActivityCreated() method and it will be fine. Thaks a lot for your help!